# Does weight affect the Earth's magnetic field?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, mass, weight, geomagnetism

Does the weight of a city influence the earths magnetic field, sort of like you can crush a magnet by putting more weight on the magnet then it can handle, for example an extremely heavy hammer?

Comment: You know what's Hawking radiation? Please see whether your question matches with the tags before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) is not due to magnetized matter distributed uniformly from the surface to the core. Most of the field comes from the motions of the [liquid core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth)

> Unlike a bar magnet, [Earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field)  changes over time because it is generated by a [geodynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory) (in Earth's case, the motion of molten iron alloys in its outer core).

[image: earth]

> [Cutaway diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Earth_internal_structure.png) of Earth's internal structure (to scale) with inset showing detailed breakdown of structure (not to scale)

We live  where the mountains are in the figure above and it is obvious that only catastrophic impacts with similar size celestial bodies would affect the geometry of the core and thus change the boundary conditions for the dynamo. 
Any effect of weight on the liquid core has already happened at the creation period of the earth.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields are never ever affected by the weight of the magnet.

The total mass of the earth never changes. Cities are made from materials from the earth, or manufactured materials which have raw materials from earth. As the mass of Earth doesn't change, there is no effect on the magnetic field like hammering.

Moreover, please don't think that the earth has a bar magnets inside it that can be hammered or magnetised and demagnetised. Though in theory we sometimes explain like that, this is absolutely conceptual,  and no practical evidence has been found. Moreover, actual cause of earth's magnetic field is different.

Comment: Thank you so much, this website is all of a sudden really cool. :)

Comment: The temp falls down to 0K sometimes :-D